# Jointly distributed random variables-Statistics

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Suppose that $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are jointly distributed random variables, that is, they are defined on the same sample space. Suppose that we also have the following.

$$E(X)=5 $$

$$E(Y)=-3 $$

$$E(Z)=-7 $$

$$Var(X)=49 $$

$$Var(Y)=32 $$

$$Var(Z)= 47 $$

Compute the values of the expressions below.

E(-2Z-4)=

E((5z-3X)/4))=

Var(5Y+2)=

E(-5Z^2)=

I tried to substitute 1.$$E(-2Z-4)= -2(-7)-4=10$$ Is this format correct?
Please Help!

Comment: I tried one, is it correct or wrong?

Comment: @Naam2 For the formats: just put $ at the beginning and end of each expression. I did some for you.

Answer (score 0):

$E(-2Z-4)= -2(-7)-4=10$ is right because

$$E(-2Z-4)= E(-2Z) +E(-4)$$

$$-2E(Z) +E(-4)$$

$$-2E(Z) +(-4)$$

$$-2E(Z) -4$$

$$ = -2(-7)-4=10$$

The other two that have only $E$ and not $Var$ are similar. For the $Var$, use the rule that

$$Var(aY+b) = a^2Var(Y)$$